# Retrieving rgb values from flask_colorpicker

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Ive been checking out the flask_colorpicker module, but I cant seem to manage to get the rgb color value to the backend to do anything with it. So far i've tried to  use the flask request module as well as WTForms but neither accomplished my goal. Im pretty experienced in python but web development using flask is very new to me so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a route like this in your flask app:

```
@app.route('/color', methods=['POST'])
def color():
    print(request.form.get('rgb'))
    return redirect('/')
```

And you need to post the value from a form in your view (assuming you have `{{ colorpicker.picker(ids=['.color']) }}`):

```
<form action="/color" method="post">
    <input name="rgb" class='color' value='rgba(0,255,0,1)' />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then if you click the submit button you will get the RGB value on the flask server console.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. Is there any value in having the color() function separate from the function displaying the index? I was able to get it to work by incorporating the two functions into one, but i'm not what the best practice is.